# How to convert an unlabled key value pair dictionary data into 2 columns in Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have an array as input in key value pair:

test = {'a':32, 'b':21, 'c':92}

I have to get the result in a new data frame as follows:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 32 |
| b | 21 |
| c | 92 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
test = {"a": 32, "b": 21, "c": 92}

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": test.keys(), "col2": test.values()})
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  col1  col2
0    a    32
1    b    21
2    c    92
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me out, issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 2):

Using unpacking:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([*test.items()], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

Using a Series:

```
df = pd.Series(test, name='col2').rename_axis('col1').reset_index()
```

output:

```
  col1  col2
0    a    32
1    b    21
2    c    92
```

Answer (score 1):

There's maybe shorter / better ways of doing this but here goes

```
test = {'a':32, 'b':21, 'c':92}

df = pd.DataFrame(test, index=[0])
df = df.stack().reset_index(-1).iloc[:, ::-1]
df.columns = ['col2', 'col1']
df.reset_index()
```